# How to access the controls in HeaderTemplate section of DataGrid using VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been trying for several hours to find help but I could not find anything specific related to my query on stackoverflow. My problem is that I want to access a checkbox(asp.net control) which is inside the HeaderTemplate of DataGrid using **VB.NET**. I have found a few partial answers(coded in C#) on stackoverflow but I could not get a clue out of them.

Comment: Do you want to access the checkbox in JavaScript or code behind?

Comment: Actually I want to access it and then call the focus method so that when page loads then it gets focused. It doesn't matter whether I code it in JavaScript or code behind. If you know how to access the checkbox which is placed in HeaderTemplate, through javascript then you can proceed to help me with that too.

Comment: Accessing the checkbox in JavaScript/jQuery should probably be a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with using DataGrid.  That's a relic from ASP.NET 1.0.  It was replaced with GridView 10 years ago.  It's only supported for backwards compatibility.  You might find some answers [here](https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/546193-getting-datagrid-header-information) or [here](https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/322659-finding-header-item-datagrid)

Comment: Anyways, thanks for sharing those links.